# Node.js express.Router ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND when import the new routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, types

I am experiencing a weird error. I was just creating a new folder to separate my routes.

Inside I created the routes using the `express.Router` API and I exported the router itself.

Here is how the code looks like inside `post-routes.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get( '/', ( req, res ) =>
{
    res.send( 'This is working' );
} );

export default router;
```

Ok. All I have to do now is to import it inside my `index.ts` and create a root route for my `post-routes.ts` file.

Please tell me if you see something wrong in my approach.

`index.ts` file:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import postRouter from './routes/post-routes';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use( '/posts', postRouter );


app.use( express.json( { limit: '30mb' } ) );
app.use( express.urlencoded( { limit: '30mb', extended: true } ) );
app.use( cors() );

app.listen( PORT, () => console.log( `listening at ${ PORT }` ) );
```

Good. Now to offer as much information as I possibly can, I will insert the following:

1. File structure inside my project:

[image: FILE STRUCTURE]

2. `package.json` file configuration:

[image: PACKAGE.JSON FILE]

As you can see, I am using the `"type": "module"` to be able to use import inside my node application. As for the typescript, I am getting no compiling errors, so `index.ts` sees the `post-routes.ts` file so I would expect that `index.js` would see `post-routes.js` file as well. But the server throws the error below. How can this be?

`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'E:\Github\hospytal-fasion\server\dist\routes\post-routes' imported from E:\Github\hospytal-fasion\server\dist\index.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from making sure that `target` and `module` are set to `esnext` in your `tsconfig.json`, make sure to include file extensions in your imports. i.e. try changing the following line:

```
import postRouter from './routes/post-routes';
```

to

```
import postRouter from './routes/post-routes.js';
```

Comment: That is correct. With one exception. It has to be `.js` extention. I am already using `esnext` in target and module in my `tsconfig.json`. The `tsc` is not converting `.ts` extensions to `.js` ones.

Comment: what if we dont want add .js at the end? like we do in react.what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

you have to import **"./routes/post-routes.js"**  (here **".js"** needed)

if you use old require methos you don't need need **.js** you only need
**require("./routes/post-routes")**

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Your answer is substantially a copy of the accepted one; while answering, be sure to add some other information,  so that it gets better